# Manipulating contrast etc within a vector of colours

Tags: r, colors

I'm seeking any efficient way to perform simple manipulations on colour vectors in R, such as brightness and contrast.  I have a hacky method that converts hex-string to numerical values and adjusts these by, for example, increasing/decreasing values for lightness, or rescaling them for lightness contrast, before converting back to hex.  It works but is too slow to run interactively, and I can't see any libraries (e.g. colorspace) that have this functionality.  Does anyone know of an alternative method?  Thanks in advance.

This illustrates the flow for darkening (the simplest manipulation):

```
cols = rainbow(100)
d = data.frame(x = 1:100, y0=rep(0,100), y1=rep(100,100))

plot_cols = function(colours){
  plot.new(); plot.window(xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100))
  segments(d$x, d$y0, d$x, d$y1, col=colours, lwd=5)
}
plot_cols(cols)
cols_num = t(col2rgb(cols))/255
plot_cols( rgb(cols_num * .5) )
```

Contrast effects require standard deviation `sd` which is I think the bottleneck.

Comment: [A related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26314701/980833).

Comment: Thanks Josh. Looks useful for saturation, sadly not contrast