# Adjust the saturation and brightness of RGB raster colours

Tags: r, colors, raster, r-raster

In my example I have a `r` raster:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10) 
set.seed(1)
r1 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 150))
r2 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 200))
r3 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 150))
r <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
names(r)=c("R","G","B")
```

Now, I'd like to adjust the saturation and brightness of RGB colours in this `r` raster and save the changes on a new image in tif format. I try several packages, but anyone modifies directly `raster` or `terra` images without format modifications.

Please any help with it?

Comment: I would have a look on `scales::muted()` and this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314701/r-reducing-colour-saturation-of-a-colour-palette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can set the RGB channels with "terra"

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10) 
set.seed(1)
r1 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 150))
r2 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 200))
r3 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 150))
r <- c(r1, r2, r3)
names(r)=c("R","G","B")

RGB(r) <- 1:3
plot(r)
```

Change the saturation

```
x <- colorize(r, to="hsv")
x$saturation <- x$saturation / 2
RGB(x, type="hsv") <- 1:3
rr <- colorize(x, to="rgb")
plot(rr)
```

And with writeRaster, the RGB channels are preserved (with file formats that support that)

```
s <- writeRaster(rr, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
s
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : test.tif 
#colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
#names       : red, green,  blue 
#min values  : 157,   172, 150.5 
#max values  : 198,   232, 205.5
```

Comment: Please, Robert Hijmans in your example I have the errors:
RGB(x, type="hsv") <- 1:3
Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (type = "hsv")
rr <- colorize(x, to="rgb")
Error: [] input color scheme should be one of 'hsv', 'hsi' or 'hsl'

Comment: Are you using the current version of terra?

Comment: Thanks, @Robert Hijmans you are sure, my package was not updated. Problem solved!!

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10) 
set.seed(1)
r1 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 150))
r2 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 200))
r3 <- setValues(r, rpois(100, 150))
r <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
names(r)=c("R","G","B")

terra::plotRGB(r)
```

[image]

Have found a nice `{colormod}` package (https://github.com/briandconnelly/colormod), which seems to be made for this purpose :). Edit: changed `adjust_rgb()` to `adjust_hsv()` function:

```r
mutemute <- function(x) {
  r <- x[[1, "R"]]
  g <- x[[1, "G"]]
  b <- x[[1, "B"]]
  
  rgb(r/255, g/255, b/255) |>
    colormod::adjust_hsv(s = -0.1, v =  -0.1) |>
    col2rgb() |>
    t()
}

x <- r
for(i in 1:10) {
  for(j in 1:10) {
    x[i, j] <- mutemute(r[i,j])
  }
}

terra::plotRGB(x)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Please, Grzegorz in my real problem doesn't work (`RGB.one.img.UTM.normalized.F` is my raster name): for(i in 1:RGB.one.img.UTM.normalized.F@ncols) {
     for(j in 1:RGB.one.img.UTM.normalized.F@nrows) {
         x[i, j] <- mutemute(RGB.one.img.UTM.normalized.F[i,j])
     }
 }
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error function 't': 'color intensity nan, not in [0,1]'

Comment: I guess it's caused by NA values in the cells. You could filter out such cells prior to applying function. But Robert's solution below is much more robust.